# TypeError: generate_user_key() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'

Tags: python, pastebin

i am getting such error

```sh
C:\Users\visitor\PycharmProjects\pastebinhacker\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/visitor/PycharmProjects/pastebinhacker/pasteb.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/visitor/PycharmProjects/pastebinhacker/pasteb.py", line 5, in <module>
    my_key = PastebinAPI.generate_user_key(api_dev_key,username,paa,)
TypeError: generate_user_key() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I read the documentation of that Module and it seems all right

```
from pastebin import PastebinAPI
api_dev_key = '72e257e0475e78c2eed3db0bd68088a8'
username='san1211'
paa='sadasdiuaosd'
my_key = PastebinAPI.generate_user_key(api_dev_key,username,paa,)
print (my_key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate a `PastebinAPI` object first.

Then you can call `generate_user_key` on that object with your parameter.

Example:

```py
from pastebin import PastebinAPI

api_dev_key = '72e257e0475e78c2eed3db0bd68088a8'
username='san1211'
paa='12awweqqwe'

pastbinapi_object = PastebinAPI() # Create your object to work with

my_key = pastbinapi_object.generate_user_key(api_dev_key,username,paa) # Call class method on that object.
print (my_key)
```

Result:

```py
40ebfabed51dd3179a3f97f37f71c213
```